# Finding p- subgroup order

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reviewing for my exam in algebra and i need help to answer the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime number that devides $|G|$ and suppose that $G=p^kn$ with p doesn't devides $n$. For $1\le j\le k$, let $m_j(G)$ be the number of subgroups of $G$ of order $p^j$.
>
> Suppose that $p^2$ devides $|G|$.

Let $X=\left\{(H,K)|H<K<G, |H|=p,|K|=p^2\right\}$.

> Show that $|X|=m_1(G) \pmod p$ and $|X|=m_2(G) \pmod p$ and conclude that $m_2(G)=1 \pmod p$

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please I need help.

Comment: Please , is there any hint so I can start solve this problem ? Thanks